# Why does my Kotlin Flow onCompletion never run?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

So I have a flow where I need it to emit a value from cache, but at the end it will make an API call to pull values in case there was nothing in cache (or refresh the value it has). I am trying this

```
override val data: Flow<List<Data>> = dataDao.getAllCachedData()
    .onCompletion {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
                requestAndCacheDataOrEmitError()
            }
        }
    }
    .map { entities ->
        entities
            .map { it.toData() }
            .filter { it !is Data.Unknown }
    }
    .filterNotNull()
    .catch { emitRepositoryError(it) }
```

So the idea is that we emit the cache, and then make an API call to fetch new data regardless of the original mapping. But I do not want it blocking. For example, if we use this flow, I do not ever want the calling function to be blocked by the onCompletion.

I think the problem is that the `onCompletion` never runs. I set some breakpoints/logs and it never runs at all, even outside of the `coroutineScope`.

Comment: A Flow from a DAO only completes when you cancel the coroutine that is collecting it. When do you want completion to be? Right after the first value of the flow? Do you only care about the first value?

Comment: I see, I did not know that it would only run on cancel. I care about the first value, but there are cases where there is no data in the cache yet, so I want the function in onCompletion to run that will update the cache, and the flow will emit a new value. It should emit once more after the onCompletion runs. I basically expect this to emit twice. Once to pull from cache, and the second time after the onCompletion finishes which would update the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the work you are doing but I think when you are collecting flow on a certain scope. You end the scope that flow will be put into onCompletion

```
 var job : Job? = null
fun scan() {
    job =  viewModelScope.launch {
        bigfileManager.bigFile.collect {
            if (it is ResultOrProgress.Result) {
                _bigFiles.value = it.result ?: emptyList()
            } else {
                _updateProgress.value = (it as ResultOrProgress.Progress).progress ?: 0
            }

        }
    }
}

fun endScreen(){
    job?.cancel()
}
```